# calculate statistics and/or a function on multiple columns in subsets of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, multiple-columns, tapply

I have a dataframe (sample of the following form):

```
DateTime                Ind1  Ind2  V1  V2  Ac1  Ac2  w1  w2   w3  shift
2016-05-01 00:01:00      U     A    5   7   20   100  50  70   200   1
2016-05-01 00:01:20      U     A    5   7   20   109  35  77   140   1
2016-05-01 00:01:40      U     A    5   7   40   120  55  97   160   1
...
2016-05-01 00:08:20      U     A    5   7   15   157  70  70   204   2
...
2016-05-02 00:08:20      U     A    5   7   28   147  65  90   240   2
...
2016-05-02 00:20:00      U     A    5   7   35   210  45  100  167   3
```

I need a new dataframe where some statistics (e.g. mean, standard deviation) for the columns v1 to w3 are listed for each date-and-shift combination, something similar to the following:

```
Date      shift   Ind1  Ind2  avgV1  sdV1   avgV2 sdV2  avgAC1 ....   
2016-05-01   1      U     A    5.3    2.9    7.8   4.5   108  .....
2016-05-01   2      U     A    6.7    3.5    8.9   5.0   99 .....
```

SOLUTION TRIED:
I can do the following steps.

1) extract date from DateTime

```
df$Date <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

2) label the data by date and shift.

```
df$DateShift <- paste(df$Date, df$shift)
```

3) for each subset, calculate some statistics on a col:

```
tmp_df <- data.frame(levels(as.factor(df$DateShift)))
avgV1 <- tapply(df$V1, df$DateShift, FUN=mean) 
sdV1 <- tapply(df$V1, df$DateShift, FUN=sd)
avgV2<- tapply(df$V2, df$DateShift, FUN=mean) 
....
```

However, I have more than 50 columns in the original dataframe, with different types of names (not as simple as in the example above).
Moreover, the statistics that I want to compute may vary (say, calculation of max and min, or some other user-defined function).

So I don't want to code by hand for the different combinations of columns and type of statistic (mean, standard dev, etc.)
What is the way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure the `dplyr` solutions are coming, but the `doBy` package works very well for this kind of thing, unless you have many (millions+) rows, in which case it will be slow.

```
library(doBy)
df_avg <- summaryBy(. ~ Date + Shift, FUN=c(mean, median, sd), data=df, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Will give a dataframe with `V1.mean`, `V1.median`, and so on.
The `. ~` means "summarize all numeric variables". If you want to keep information from some factors in the dataframe, use the argument `id.vars = ~somefac+somefac2`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Remko. How to leave out the columns (Ind1 and Ind2 above) on which statistics should not be computed?

Comment: I think you could use the `id.vars` argument and then remove them afterwards, or just keep them as is and toss them out when done, e.g. `dfr <- dfr[,!grepl("Ind1|Ind2", names(dfr))]` (have to do it that way to remove `Ind1.mean`, `Ind1.median`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(DateTime)) %>%
  group_by(Date, shift) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```